# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - July 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the tenth edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for July 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      340
2   Mononeeth                  230
3   bmike                      190
4   nohillside                 160
5   Tetsujin                   140
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,446 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-07-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   bmike                    120
2   Nimesh Neema             119
3   Matt                      80
4   IconDaemon                58
5   nohillside                52
```

A big thank you to all 17 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,416
2   Monomeeth                 432
3   bmike                     314
4   Nimesh Neema              287
5   Melvin Jefferson          151
```

A big thank you to all 55 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. Note: Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     58
2   nohillside                50
3   Mark                      32
4   IconDaemon                25
5   fsb                       21
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                175
2   nohillside               132
3   fsb                      118
4   Nimesh Neema              97
5   bmike                     63
```

A big thank you to all 38 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     88
2   Monomeeth                 68
3   Glorfindel                47
4   IconDaemon, Mark          23
5   nohillside                19
```

A big thank you to all 25 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     43
2   Tetsujin                  24
3   fsb                       17
4   Mark                      15
5   nohillside                13
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    23
2   fsb                      12
3   Tetsujin                 11
4   Mark, IconDaemon          6 
5   nohillside                5
```

A big thank you to all 15 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    79
2   nohillside               37
3   Nimesh Neema             31
4   JBis                     30
5   Glorfindel               27
```

A big thank you to all 37 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Why does 0^0 in the macOS and iOS calculator give different results on different versions?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/329518/168832)

   - Posted by: mspanc
   - Votes: **18**
2. [Homebrew: Rollback from Python 3.7 to Python 3.6.5.x?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/329187/168832)

   - Posted by: clay
   - Votes: **16**
3. [How to view any folder as if it was desktop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/329173/168832)

   - Posted by: Gabriel Brookman
   - Votes: **15**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [Is this Apple charger cable genuine?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329341/168832)

   - Posted by: Scottmeup
   - Votes: **44**
2. [How do I change my macOS user account UUID to stop Apple tracking me?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329234/168832)

   - Posted by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **37**
3. [Why does 0^0 in the macOS and iOS calculator give different results on different versions?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329539/168832)

   - Posted by: undercat
   - Votes: **22**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Is this Apple charger cable genuine?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/329340/168832)

   - Posted by: MicroMachine
   - Views: **6,241**
2. [Why does 0^0 in the macOS and iOS calculator give different results on different versions?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/329518/168832)

   - Posted by: mspanc
   - Views: **4,648**
3. [How do I change my macOS user account UUID to stop Apple tracking me?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/329233/168832)

   - Posted by: IOIOIO
   - Views: **3,181**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [mspanc](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/122376/mspanc)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Scottmeup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/43053/scottmeup)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [MicroMachine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/132532/micromachine)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In July our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 383 flags with an average handling time of 49 minutes. In summary, we also:

- deleted 270 comments
- deleted 242 posts
- closed 159 posts
- edited 243 posts
- created 110 posts
- created 540 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

Comment: Can't believe I'm in this one. Didn't do much. Lol. Thanks.

Comment: I have always wondered, how is @PeterJ 's account able to cast more than 40 votes in a single day (which as I understand is the limit for the total votes a single account can cast in a day!). Also, his account is the one which consistently has a high count for votes casted.

Comment: @JBis Every little bit helps! :) Thanks again for all your efforts, no matter how big or small you think they were!

Comment: @NimeshNeema I was wondering when someone was going to notice/ask that! You're absolutely correct that we all have a limit of 40 votes per day, but the way it works is that if any of the posts you've voted on ends up being deleted on the same day, then you effectively get that vote back. For example, say you've voted on 40 posts today and then one of those is deleted (e.g. someone deletes their answer, a Mod deletes a post, etc) then you'll actually get one more vote up your sleeve for the day.

Comment: As for PeterJ, he spends quite a bit of time on [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), so I suspect his account is extremely active in voting down posts as SPAM and, as those posts get deleted, he gets more votes (this is an educated guess - not even Mods can identify what posts a user votes on). Anyway, over the course of a month, those extra votes add up. So, nothing *dodgy* going on (not that you were implying that!), it's just one way he's an active contributor to the site. :)